# html/js if loop writes to specific file location

Tags: javascript, html, decision-tree

I'm trying to figure out how to write a program that loops 20 questions and then goes to a decision tree to help people make decisions. Essentially it would work like. . .
"user: I want to make more money. questions would go like..
what can you do to increase income? part time job, passive income, yard sale, etc. after all the questions it goes to a decision tree based on your answers.  Are you willing to get a part time job, do you have things to sell at a yard sale, can you put away money for a passive income? and then it creates a list of everything you would have said yes to and puts it in a file. This gives the user a list of ideas of their own choosing to help decide how to move forward with improving situations.

A couple of things I quickly realized while researching the code(HTML/Javascript) I would need to use.
1.) a loop for the 20 questions; I don't know how to point my JavaScript loop to the html. And I saw where it said you can't loop in html. I assumed it may have worked when I used

```html
<script>src"app.js"</script>
```

but no luck

2.) I located something that said I cant specify a file's save location either. at this point (code's run and would have offered to download) do I just need to write a download  button to appear when the final question has been answered or is there a better way to go about this?

Here is the js  for the while loop and writing the file

```js
// loop 20 questions; variable="num"
//if statement for print; variable="Question"; writes result to .txt file
let num = 1
while (num <= 10){
    if(num == 21){
        break;
    }
    if Question == "yes" or "Yes"{
//requires FS module; is where writefile function is defined.
        const fs = require('fs')
//Data which will write in the file.
        let data= num
//write data in text file ""
        fs.writeFile('This is the fileName, data,(err)=> {
// In case of an error, throw err.
            if (err) throw err;
        })
    }
    console.log(num);
    num++;
}
```

No css file currently started

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>This is a title</title>

<!--Custom CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">   

</head>
<body>
    <input type="Is there something you wish to work on?">
    <script>src="app.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any and all assistance is appreciated.
I'm also wondering if I should just switch to trying this in python but I've been trying to learn html/javascript so I figured it be best to confirm that this is something that can be accomplished with the 2 languages.

Comment: your `<script>src"app.js"</script>` syntax is invalid

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  wait is it supposed to be
 ~~~html 
<script src="./app.js"></script>
  ~~~

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#examples

Answer (score 0):

I am new and not expert but let me try to help you.
I have 3 suggestions for you. Try this out and see if it helps

1. Use your this to link js file:

```
<script defer src="app.js"></script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#examples

2. Not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve just after while loops
   starts put the condition to enter the loop while num is less or equal to
   10 and just after that you put if condition for num equals to 21 which
   simply never gonna be the case
3. Use try catch block to handle errors which may not affect the output but
   improves the readability(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)